# Cannot change access modifiers when overriding 'protected' inherited member 'Windows.UI.Xaml.FrameworkElement.OnApplyTemplate() Error In Wp8.1 WinRt

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

This Code is Working in WP8.0 but in WP8.1 Universal Apps i got the error.

```
 public override void OnApplyTemplate()
 {
      base.OnApplyTemplate();
      //Some Statements
 }
```

**Exception**

> Cannot change access modifiers when overriding 'protected' inherited member 'Windows.UI.Xaml.FrameworkElement.OnApplyTemplate()

Comment: Did you try changing the public to protected?

Comment: Yes tried that one but i am getting another error is  "The namespace 'LART.Controls' already contains a definition for 'MyclassName'"

Comment: `OnApplyTemplate` is defined as protected as per [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement.onapplytemplate) msdn documentation so you definitely need to mark it as protected instead of public. It is hard to tell you about other issue you are facing without some more details or relavant code.

Answer (score 15):

"Error CS0507 can also occur if a class attempts to override a method marked as **protected internal** defined in referenced metadata. In this situation, *the overriding method should be marked as **protected***."

- Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0507

So, just simply remove the "internal" keyword from your overriding method, and keep it only "protected".

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible to change the visibility modifier when overriding a method. `OnApplyTemplate` is defined as `protected` in the base class, so you need to declare it the same way:

```
 protected override void OnApplyTemplate()
 {
      base.OnApplyTemplate();
      //Some Statements
 }
```

In the improbable case you'd need to access this method from outside of the class, you can call it by declaring another public method:

```
 public void ApplyTemplate()
 {
     this.OnApplyTemplate();
 }

 protected override void OnApplyTemplate()
 {
      base.OnApplyTemplate();
      //Some Statements
 }
```

Comment: You are wrong in second snippet you can not have method overloaded with only different access modifier. [Here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/taNJSu) is dot net fiddle.

Comment: When i tried your code i got the Fallowing Error is   "The namespace 'LART.Controls' already contains a definition for 'MyclassName'"

Comment: @JenishRabadiya I didn't overload it, I gave it a different name

Comment: sorry! at first look both looks like same..!

Comment: @DeviPrasad There's nothing called 'MyclassName' in that code snippet, so your error comes from elsewhere.